# cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type to an rvalue of type during cmake --build

Tags: c++, machine-learning, cmake, pass-by-reference, eigen

I am trying to build my project with cmake, I am using different libraries for this one of which contains the following function:

```cpp
  void forward(const MatrixType& input, MatrixType& output) {
    // Copy the input to the internal state buffer
    states_[0] = input;
    // Compute forward pass through hidden layers
    for (size_t i=0; i < dimensions_.size()-2; i++) {
      states_[i+1] = weights_[i]*states_[i] + biases_[i];
      activation_.evaluate(states_[i+1]);
    }
    // Compute forward pass of the linear output layer
    states_.back() = weights_.back()*states_.end()[-2] + biases_.back();
    // Copy the output state to the provided buffer
    output = states_.back();
  }
```

In my own file, `RLController.cpp`, I am trying to call this function at line 260 as `ctrl_->forward(obScaled_, actScaled_);`.
Both `obScaled_` and `actScaled_` are defined in my header file as `Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1>  obScaled_, actScaled_` and are set to zero with `ctrl.actScaled_.setZero(ctrl.mlp_output_size);`.
When I do so I get this error:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘eignets::MultiLayerPerceptron<float, eignets::ActivationType::HyperbolicTangent>::MatrixType&’ {aka ‘Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>&’} to an rvalue of type ‘eignets::MultiLayerPerceptron<float, eignets::ActivationType::HyperbolicTangent>::MatrixType’ {aka ‘Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>’}
> 257 |     ctrl_->forward(obScaled_, actScaled_);

Isn't that exactly how you are supposed to call by reference?

What I find weird is that it used to work but after migration to another folder it stopped working. But still during build there don't seem to be any errors related to dependencies.

For completeness this is the function defined in RLController.cpp where I call this forward function:

```cpp
void RLController::ComputeAction(float obs[], int obs_size){
    // obs is the observation vector from the environment
    // compute the action vector with the observation vector and the ctrl_ model

    // scale the observation vector
    getObMean(obs);
    getObStd(obs);
    for (int i = 0; i < obs_size; ++i) {  
        obScaled_[i] = ((obs[i] - mean)) / std_dev;  
    }

    ctrl_->forward(obScaled_, actScaled_);

    // convert the action vector to double
    actDouble_ = actScaled_.cast<double>();
    exact_ -> setDTarget(actDouble_); 

}
```

forward should just pass `obScaled_` through a multi layer perceptron that I have already trained and give me 3 action values in `actScaled_`, that I passed by reference. I am getting stuck at building with cmake. if I cancel out line 260 from RLController.cpp it builds successfully.

Comment: `actScaled_` is a `Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1>`, but `MatrixType` is `Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>`? MRE: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/q96zWWWTW

Answer (score -1):

The passed variable actScaled was defined as Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1> instead of Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>, trivial solution. Thank you chtz.

Comment: Maybe rather change the type `MatrixType` to `Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1>`, if possible (or make your function a template function). Also, do you actually need to store `states_` in a container?

Comment: Please, format the code in your answer, and refrain from unnecessary comments.